# hello js with twitter giving error of callback_url

Tags: twitter, authentication, hello.js, callbackurl

I got this error:-Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings.

i also register my appid and secret key to https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/#manage-apps

ad my redirect_url and callback_url both are same

When i print log on console 
console.log(hello(network).getAuthResponse()); //for twitter

here is the error

display: "popup"
error: {code: "auth_failed", message: ""}
error_message: "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings"
network: "twitter"
oauth: {version: "1.0a", auth: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate", request: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", token: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"}
oauth_proxy: "https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy"
redirect_uri: "https://tvderby.tv/dev/index.php/customerController/nearByTheaters"
scope: "basic,email"

Comment: Are you using a DNS redirect? that probably will not work, or you'll need to have the redirect URL registered and whitelisted too.

Comment: No i am not using it. and my callback url in twitter app and redirect url in my code are same but still have issue: "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings" their is any think else i have to do?